# Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

Estoy realizando un flutter splash screen, es mi primera vez y estoy aprendiendo, es en yaml.

```
    dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter 
flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19

 flutter_native_splash: 
   
    android: true
    ios: true
    web: false

   image: assets/images/inicio.png
```

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos de tipo yaml tienen que tener una indentación exacta para poder funcionar correctamente. Veo que en el código que has puesto, `flutter_native_splash` está puesto dos veces:

```yaml
flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19

 flutter_native_splash: 
   
    android: true
    ios: true
    web: false
```

Además de que el segundo está indentado de forma incorrecta. Puede que lo de la indentación sea que lo has copiado/pegado sin darle formato, pero el que esté duplicado seguro que es un problema.

Recuerda que este tipo de archivos es muy delicado con como están los datos organizados. Tienen que tener la indentación exacta para poder funcionar, un espacio más o menos, y ya no funciona.

Recuerda, además, para la próxima que todo el código, ya sea código como tal o errores, deben ser expuesto como texto entre sus etiquetas correspondientes; no añadas imágenes para este tipo de contenido.